# How to switch views in storyboard (programmatically and with IB)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

After struggling a bit to find the right answer for my work, and after going through numerous posts on the net (and some hours to sort out why those posts didn't work) I thought it would be helpful with a short and definite answer on how to do this in ios7+

So, using Interface builder you want to create a Seque between your view controllers that you want to transition between. All the posts Ive seen does this Ctrl-dragging from the views inside the work area in IB. You need to take use of the view hierarchy structure to the left, or it might not let you create the seque!
Choose "Present modally seque" (or you probably wouldn't be reading this).
Now go to the attributes inspector for the seque. Here you need to fill in "Identifier" for your seque.
Then go to your code and use this method to perform the transition:
    `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:sequeIdentifierString sender:self]`
Voila!

You can also easily do the transition without using seques. 
Use this code (remember to go to your view controllers attribute inspector and fill out the Identifier!):

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
MyViewController *myVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:myVCIdentifierString];
[self presentViewController:myVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I hope this is useful, it sure would have been for me.
Best of luck!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is an answer

Comment: I have seen question asked to be answered like this before, finding it helpful. Don't see why its off-topic. Best regards